# How to set job order for monitor view in jenkins job DSL groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm creating Build Monitor view with DSL Script, but there is no method in API to set the job order. I can set the order manually in configuration after view is created, but I need to do that within the script.

I'm using https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/buildMonitorView as a reference. The only way I suspect it could be possible is configure(Closure) method, but I would still have the same question of how to do it.

My current code:

```
biuldMonitorView("name-of-the-view") {
    jobs {
        regex("some regex to include jobs")
        recurse()
    }
    // I would expect something like:
    view {
        orderByFullName()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error and `println` calls everywhere I came to this solution:

```
biuldMonitorView("name-of-the-view") {
    jobs { // This part is as before
        regex("some regex to include jobs")
        recurse()
    }
    // The solution:
    view.remove(view / order)
    view / order(class: "com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugins.buildmonitor.order.ByFullName")
}
```

Above solution sets job order to "Full name" instead of default "Name".

I found the `remove` idea at [Configure SVN section of job-dsl-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block#configure-svn), fully qualified names of job order options can be found in the source of [jenkins-build-monitor-plugin](https://github.com/jan-molak/jenkins-build-monitor-plugin/tree/master/build-monitor-plugin/src/main/java/com/smartcodeltd/jenkinsci/plugins/buildmonitor/order).

Comment: Hi, I have tried that and it does not work...
Did you have to add anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question today and managed to get Aivaras's proposal to work in the following way:

```
buildMonitorView("name-of-the-view") {
  // Set properties like jobs
  jobs { 
    regex("some regex to include jobs")
    recurse()
  }
  // Directly manipulate the config to set the ordering
  configure { view ->
    view.remove(view / order)
    view / order(class: "com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugins.buildmonitor.order.ByFullName")
  }
```